# Данные из json вывести на страницу

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Приходят данные в виде

```
0 {
address: "address"
name: "name"
phones: "phones"
region: "Витебск"
region_id: "19"
  },
1 {
address: "address"
name: "name"
phones: "phones"
region: "Лида"
region_id: "34"
  },
2 {
address: "address"
name: "name"
phones: "phones"
region: "Витебск"
region_id: "19"
  },
```

.....
и т.д.

Нужно создать селект со списком регионов, остальные данные необходимо вывести в таблицу.
Забить селект приходящими значениями я смогу

```
 $.ajax(settingsList).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $.each(response, function (key, item) {
      $.each(item, function (index, value) {
  
        console.log(item.region);
      });
      var gotoOption = "<li title='" + item.region +"' class='goto-option'>" + item.region+"</li>";
      $(gotoOption).appendTo('.goto-list');
      
      console.info(item.region);
    });
    $('.goto-list li').click(function (e) {
      var optionText = $(this).text();
      $('.goto-selected').text(optionText).attr('title', optionText);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Но проблема в том, что регионы дублируется, а как перебрать я не соображу и при добавлении таким образом очень заметно замедляется загрузка страницы, т.к. список большой.
Буду крайне признателен за помощь

Comment: Нужно использовать библиотеку fetch или axios, заимпортить и сделать функции, которые будут рендерить данные. Не советую использовать вашу форму запроса.

Comment: вы отфильруйте сначала нужные данные, а потом уже добавляйте, и не по одному элементу в DOM за  раз, а всю пачку разом

Comment: если бы я знал как это сделать, то несомненно сделал)
пока у меня к сожалению скудные познания

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запоминайте id которые уже добвлены куда-нибудь (`map`). А пункты просто в строковую переменную добавляйте (`list`) по мере встречи новых регионов.

```
let map = { };
let list = "";

$.each(response, function (key, item) {
    if(map[item.region_id]) return;
    map[item.region_id] = item.region_id;

    list += "<li title='" + item.region +"' class='goto-option'>" + item.region+"</li>";
});
```

потом, когда все сформировали, единожды добавьте это в DOM.

```
$(".goto-list").append(list);
```

и обработчик поадекватней навесьте

```
$('.goto-list').on('click', '.goto-option', function () {
    var optionText = $(this).text();

    $('.goto-selected').text(optionText)
                      .attr('title', optionText);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но значения все-равно повторяются (

Comment: @Leonid  там вместо `key`, надо `item.region_id`, пофиксил.

Comment: спасибо огромное, так работает